# Django ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with

Tags: python, django

I keep getting the error:

```
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

I can't figure out why either. Here is my view:

```
   def CreateWorkout(request):
    WorkoutInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(workout,exercise)
    if request.method == "POST" : 
        formset = WorkoutInlineFormSet(request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid(): 
            formset.save(); 
    else: 
        formset = WorkoutInlineFormSet()
    return render_to_response('submit.html',{'formset': formset},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And here is my template:

```
<body>
<form method="POST" action ="">
{{ formset.management_form }}
<table>
 {% for form in formset.forms %}
            {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}

        </table>
</form> 
</body>
```

I've read that you have to include the `formset.management_form`, and I have. I thought that would be an easy fix, but I haven't been able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Are you showing correct template? There doesn't seem to be submit button.

Comment: check if you dont have a typo in your formset name in your template

Answer (score 7):

I have meet this problem.

The reason is there is NO something like `form-TOTAL_FORMS, form-INITIAL_FORMS and form-MAX_NUM_FORMS)` in your `POST` data.

You should use `{{ formset.as_p }}`, this will render the management_form data from the formset. If you want to make the custom formset rendering, you should not forget the management_form of the formset to let POST data be with the mangement_form data.

Answer (score 6):

When you use inline formset, you need to provide the instance that the objects relate to.

```
# First, fetch the instance from the db
workout = code_that_fetches_instance()

if request.method == "POST" : 
    formset = WorkoutInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=workout)
    ...
else: 
    formset = WorkoutInlineFormSet(instance=workout)
```

See the example in the docs on [using an inline formset in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view) for more information.

If `workout` and `exercise` are your models, you should follow the python convention and rename them `Workout` and `Exercise`. Lowercase `workout` should be the instance that all the exercises in your formset are linked to.

Comment: Still the same error. The error is occurring during the declaration for formset underneath request.method == "POST"

Comment: After making my change did you reload the code and make a fresh get request before submitting again? Please update your question with the html output when you make a get request with my suggested change.

Comment: You haven't included the html output that I asked for. I've updated the answer with a couple more suggestions.

Comment: You get the error message on the get request as well as when you submit the form? The full traceback might be helpful. I think you need to sort out the other issues I've mentioned. I can't help you any more tonight. Hope you get it working.

Comment: are workout and exercise instances or models? I have same issue. @Alasdair, what about a form for a new model instance with related objects?

Comment: @christophe31 this question is several years old, and never got a definitive answer, so I don't think it will help you much. I think the OP named the models `workout` and `excercise`, but it would be much clearer to use `Workout` and `Excercise`. Creating a new instance and related objects at the same time is a different issue. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113047/creating-a-model-and-related-models-with-inline-formsets) might be what you are looking for. If not, please ask a new question.

Comment: you're right, this one is not 3 years old at least… ^^, thanx for the tip and sorry for the joke. (I think i fixed my issue related to chaining `if form.is_valid and formset1.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid():` which probably postponed the content validation to rendering and caused a crash… but not sure yet as I didn't produced the bug myself)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
  formset = WorkoutInlineFormSet(request.POST)
```

to this:

```
 formset = WorkoutInlineFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
```