# Django formset u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'

Tags: django, django-forms

In my Django project i use 3 forms on one view. 2 of this forms is formsets. There is how looks like my forms:

```
class HotelForm(forms.Form):
        country = forms.CharField(label=(u'Select Country'))
        city = forms.CharField(label=(u'Select City'))
        hotel = forms.ChoiceField(label=(u'Hotel Stars'))
        from_date = forms.CharField(label=(u'Date from'))
        to_date = forms.CharField(label=(u'Date to'))
        rooms = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Rooms'), min_value=1)
        food = forms.ChoiceField(label=(u'Food'),
                widget = forms.Select, choices = FOOD_CHOICES)

class TouristsForm(forms.Form):
        adult = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, initial=1)
        children = forms.IntegerField(label=(min_value=0, initial=0, required=False)

class ChildrenAgeForm(forms.Form):
        children_age = forms.IntegerField(min_value=2, max_value=10, initial=2, required=False)
```

Depending on numbers of field `rooms` of `HotelForm` i add formset `TouristsFormSet` using js:

```
$('#id_booking_form-rooms').on('change', function(e){
   var n = $('#id_booking_form-rooms').val() || 0;
   var html = "";

   for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      html += "<input id='id_tourists-TOTAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='1' name='tourists-TOTAL_FORMS'>"
      + "<input id='id_tourists-INITIAL_FORMS' type='hidden' name='tourists-INITIAL_FORMS'>"
      + "<input id='id_tourists-MIN_NUM_FORMS' type='hidden' name='tourists-MIN_NUM_FORMS'>"
      + "<input id='id_tourists-MAX_NUM_FORMS' type='hidden' name='tourists-MAX_NUM_FORMS'>"
      + "<div>Quantity of people in the room " + (i + 1) + "</div>"
      + "<br/><label for='id_tourists-" + i + "-adult'>Adults quantity:</label>"
      + "<input id='id_tourists-" + i + "-adult' type='number' name='tourists-" + i + "-adult' value='0'/>"
      + "<label for='id_tourists-" + i + "-children'>Children quantity:</label>"
      + "<input id='id_tourists-" + i + "-children' type='number' name='tourists-" + i + "-children' class='children_age' value='0'/>"
      + "<div class='extrafieldWrapperChAge'></div>";
      }
      $(".extrafieldWrapper").html(html);
});
```

Depending on number of `children` of formset `TouristsFormSet` i add formset `ChildrenAgeFormSet` using js:

```
$(".extrafieldWrapper").on('change', '.children_age', function(e){
   var n = $(this).val() || 0;
   var html = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      html += "<input id='id_childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='1' name='childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS'>"
      + "<input id='id_childrenage-INITIAL_FORMS' type='hidden' name='childrenage-INITIAL_FORMS'>"
      + "<input id='id_childrenage-MIN_NUM_FORMS' type='hidden' name='childrenage-MIN_NUM_FORMS'>"
      + "<input id='id_childrenage-MAX_NUM_FORMS' type='hidden' name='childrenage-MAX_NUM_FORMS'>"
      + "<br/><label for='id_childrenage-" + i + "-children_age'>Children Age "+(i+1)+"</label>"
      + "<input id='id_childrenage-" + i + "-children_age' type='number' value='0' name='childrenage-" + i + "children_age' />";
      }
$(this).next('.extrafieldWrapperChAge').html(html);
});
```

There is how looks like my html file:

```
<div class="large-6 columns">
   <div class="fieldWrapper">
     {% if booking_form.city.errors %}
       <ol style="list-style-type:square" >
         {% for error in booking_form.city.errors %}
           <li><strong>This field is required</strong></li>
         {% endfor %}
        </ol>
      {% endif %}
      {{ booking_form.city.label_tag }}
      {{ booking_form.city }}
     </div>
 </div>
 <!-- and other HotelForm fields -->
 <div class="extrafieldWrapper">
 <!-- here is load formset fields -->
 </div>
 <div class="row">
   <input type="submit" value="Find">
 </div>
```

and there is looks like my view:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  TouristsFormSet = formset_factory(TouristsForm, extra = 1, max_num = 15)
  ChildrenAgeFormSet = formset_factory(ChildrenAgeForm, extra = 1, max_num = 20)
  booking_form = HotelForm(request.POST, prefix='booking_form')
  tourists_formset = TouristsFormSet(request.POST, prefix='tourists')
  childrenage_formset = ChildrenAgeFormSet(request.POST, prefix='childrenage')
  if booking_form.is_valid() and tourists_formset.is_valid() and childrenage_formset.is_valid():
    ...
```

Everything work fine, but if i leave `adult`, `children` fields of `TouristsFormSet` and/or `children age` fields of `ChildrenAgeFormSet` with default value, i receive error `ValidationError at /booking/`, [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'].

I tried to compare html code in browser when i use js and without js just using `{{tourists_formset}}` and `{{childrenage_formset}}`. And its seems to me that its the [same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orbtn.jpg) . When i use formsets without js everything works fine

Also in traceback i find this line `return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)` when value of field children is 0 and `_('ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'), code='missing_management_form',`

I will be thankful if somebody will help me with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877576/django-managementform-data-is-missing-or-has-been-tampered-with)

Comment: The management form should be added once for each formset. It looks as if you are adding it once for each form. I'm also not sure why you are hardcoding `value='1'`, if the total number of forms might change.

Comment: You might find it easier to debug if you get your forms working without javascript first. Then once that's working, you can fix your javascript so that it generates the required html.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you for your comment. I tried to test forms with and without js. Without js everything works fine, i tried to compare to html and didn't find differences http://i.imgur.com/5OnRFt0.jpg?1

Comment: In traceback i see this line `return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)` when value of field `children ` is 0 and ` _('ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'),
                                code='missing_management_form',`

Comment: As I said a couple of days ago: The management form should be added once for each formset. It looks as if you are adding it once for each form. I'm also not sure why you are hardcoding value='1', if the total number of forms might change.

Comment: I'm sorry for duplicating, i'm already update my previous post. I'm duplicate `value='1'` to make code the same as without js. In original i have no this value in my code

Comment: Here's another idea to debug. Compare `request.POST` without JavaScript (when it works) and with JavaScript (when you get the error). What is the difference?

Comment: @Alasdair i'm sorry i didn't see that you said that  management form should be added once for each formset. you was absolutely wright, you can make answer

Comment: Great, glad you fixed the problem :)

Comment: Thank you very much. And sorry once again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The management form should be added once for each formset. In your JavaScript, it looks as if you are adding it once for each form.