# Inline in ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create a form for users to fill out.

The form consist of a Company model, and a Employee model.

I want users to add one company and as many Employee they want, in one form.

In django admin, this functionality is easy to accomplish with StackedInline, but what do I need to do, to have the same functionality in my public form?

---

```
#models.py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name        


class Employee(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)  
    first_name = models.CharField()  
    last_name = models.CharField()  


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

---

```
#admin.py
class EmployeeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Employee


class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [
        EmployeeInline,
    ]

    model = Company

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

---

```
#forms.py

class CompanyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company

class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
```

---

```
#views.py
def companyform_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = CompanyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            f = CompanyForm(request.POST)
            f.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/company/added/')

    else:
        form = CompanyForm()

    return render(request, 'form/formtemplate.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

---

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) is what you need:

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets.
>   These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign
>   key.

See examples here:

- [Creating a model and related models with Inline formsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113047/creating-a-model-and-related-models-with-inline-formsets)

Hope that helps.