# Django forms with data from multiple models

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

Simplest way to explain would be to just say what I'm trying to do.

I have a Visit model and a Subject model. The Visit is foreign-keyed to the Subject, so I can get the Subjects as a choice field in my form (which is a Model Form built off of the Visit model).

There is other data I want though that is related to the subject, and I was wondering what the best way to access that is.

My models, form and what I ultimately want are below.

**Models**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subject_name
    subject_name=models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True, blank=True)
    subject_number=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True, blank=True)
    birthdate=models.DateField("Date of Birth",null=True, blank=True)
    cohort=models.ForeignKey("Cohort",null=True, blank=True)

class Visit(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
    subject=models.ForeignKey("Subject")
    ageband=models.ForeignKey("AgeBand",null=True, blank=True)
    visit_date=models.DateField("Visit Date",null=True, blank=True)
```

**Form**

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Visit
        widgets = {
            'visit_date': DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}),
        }
```

**Simple Depiction of what I want in form**

Subject Name **_**  (have this)

Subject Number *_*_  (have this)

Subject Birthdate *_*_ (from Subject.birthdate, don't have this)

Visit Date *_* (have this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModelForm` only represents fields from one model.  If you want to use both models, you'll need to use an `InlineFormSet`, which allows you to combine two `ModelForm`s.  From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets):

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets. These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign key.

Here is a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113047/creating-a-model-and-related-models-with-inline-formsets) that describes how to create an `InlineFormSet`.