# Repeat fields in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to have a form containing three times two related fields (A name, and some ip address as a simple regex field)

> name1
>
> name1 IPs
>
> name2
>
> name2 IPs
>
> name3
>
> name3 IPs

name 1 and 2 are required, IPs are never. Is there a way not to repeat these fields, and/or better, to receive them as list or something like : 
[ { name, ip }, { name, ip }, { name, ip } ]

EDIT: Name and IPs are wild datas, they are not related to any model, they're used for a call to an API

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use inline formsets.

[Creating a model and related models with Inline formsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113047/creating-a-model-and-related-models-with-inline-formsets)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. There is actually no models related to this form (cause I use these datas with an API).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have forms and you want to repeat those forms right...

You can use formsets... ([formset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/)).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from django.forms import formset_factory
>>> from myapp.forms import ArticleForm
>>> ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm, extra=2)
>>> formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=[
...     {'title': 'Django is now open source',
...      'pub_date': datetime.date.today(),}
... ])

>>> for form in formset:
...     print(form.as_table())
```

You can send this formset as a context variable to render the template with these forms.

In the template.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
 <button type="submit">
</form>
```

That should work