# Cannot assign "'1'": "Groups.profile" must be a "Profile" instance

Tags: python, django

*I have Profile Model that have instance model user.. I am trying to create group using form. that group model have Profile model as instance,  so how do I select authenticated user  automatic to create group, I getting confused...*

*This is my Group Model*

```
class Groups(models.Model):
profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='my_groups', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
groups_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
cover_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/groups/', null=True, blank=True)
type_group = models.CharField(max_length=150)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
about_group = models.TextField(max_length=600)
members = models.ManyToManyField(Profile,through="GroupMember")

def __str__(self):
    return self.groups_name
```

*This is my profile Model*

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/user/profile/', null=True, blank=True)
cover_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/user/profile/', null=True, blank=True)
user_bio = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True, max_length=255)
designation = models.CharField(blank=True,null=True, max_length=255)
education = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
marital_status = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=60)
hobbies = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
location = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
mobile = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

*This is form for create group*

```
class GroupCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Groups
    fields = ('cover_pic', 'profile', 'groups_name', 'type_group', 'about_group')

profile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control input-group-text',
    'value':'',
    'id':'somesh',
    'type': 'hidden',


}))
```

*This is create group html file*

[this is html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkTdu.png)

[this is error..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjOxa.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Also add the relevant (class-based) view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set a `CharField` for profile in your form. When you send data to this form, it tries to make a `Group` record with a FK to a `CharField` for example "1" and this gives you error because you should pass `Profile` object to `Group`.

Depends on what exactly you want, there are some options.

You can use `ModelChoiceField`. Read about it in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

Or you can use `Inline FormSet` and read about it in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

And an example for `Inline FormSet` in [Creating a model and related models with Inline formsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113047/creating-a-model-and-related-models-with-inline-formsets)